Nextjs Build output is overloading my CI process, how to reduce the build output?
During CI build on remote machine, the npm build command of nextjs 13 yield to the terminal a lot of output (of things in process, things that the build is doing during the build etc)
is it possible to reduce the noise in the terminal to minimum during build to production?
the reason is, that whenever there is a problem or an issue my browser get stuck and can't load the entire terminal output of the build process (So i can't tell what is the issue during build production)

I don't think its possible, nextjs build command doesn't provide any verbosity option. One way to solve is pipe stdout to a file and download it when you need to analyze but you won't see any output in terminal during build.

Well you can try your luck configuring the next.config.js file or you can try running the build command using some sort of shell script to execute within the pipline and then grep or rgrep specific messages or log levels i.e., next build | grep -i 'ERROR' NOTE: i flag ignore case sensitivity.
A cleaner approach if configuring the next.config.js or a shell script is not an option (i.e., suppress using a lambda func. etc.). You can look into structuring your logs using a third-party (e.g. next-logger, pino, etc.) and enable nextjs experimental feature; you would then configure the third-party library to ignore log levels or create a custom handler to transform sensitive info etc.
As a last option you can use DEBUG=*,-connect:* environmental variable. based on the specific log pattern you would replace the DEBUG env var value. I suggested this option last because you would NOT want this in production.
Hope that helps.
